# Popup window and SpringMVC - data interchanging. How to do?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am creating the first web-app. I use SpringMVC + Hibernate + JSP.
I run into one complex situation and can't solve it.

I have a JSP with table on it. This table contains user questions. Each row contains questionId, questionMessage, authorName, postDate, answerMessage and answerPosDate. I put into each row 3 buttons: Reply, Change and Delete. Admin of the site can log in, and modify each row - each answer using these 3 buttons. When Admin click Reply or Change buttons, a popupWindow opens. Popupwindow contains textarea and two buttons: Save and Cancel.

I don't know how to do binding between each row column (questionId, questionMessage, authorName, postDate, answerMessage and answerPostDate) and Reply-Change-Delete buttons. Here is snippet of JSP

```
<div id="main">
    <c:if test="${!empty questionList}">
        <table class="answersTable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>questionId</th>
                <th>questionMessage</th>
                <th>authorName</th>
                <th>postDate</th>
                <th>answerMessage</th>
                <th>answerPostDate</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${questionList}" var="question">
                <tr>
                    <td>${question.message}</td>
                    <td>${question.authorName}</td>
                    <td>${question.postDate}</td>
                    <td>${question.answer}</td>
                    <td>${question.answerDate}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button onclick="showPopupWindow(); setAttributes(${question.id}, 0)">Reply</button>
                        </br>
                        <button onclick="showPopupWindow(); setAttributes(${question.id}, 1)">Change</button>
                        </br>
                        <button windowCase = 2">Delete</button>
                        </br>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </c:if>
</div>
<div id="popupWindow">
    <div class="messageBoxTitle">Modify answer</div>
    <form:form accept-charset="utf-8" action="/add_answer" commandName="question" method="GET">
        <form:textarea class="messageBox" maxlength="255" rows="5"
                       cols="50" path="answer"></form:textarea></br></br>
        <input class="sendBtn" type="submit" value="Save">
        <button class="sendBtn" onclick="closePopupWindow()">Cancel</button>
    </form:form>
</div>
```

My controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add_answer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addAnswer(@ModelAttribute("question") Question question) {
    question.setAnswerDate(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
    questionService.modifyQuestion(question);
    return "redirect:/answers";
}
```

questionService snippet:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public void modifyQuestion(Question question) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(question);
}
```

When I click on Save-button of popup window, hibernate gives me an error, that the question object is not enought fulled. And it's true! Cosa I send only answerPostDate into question inside method addAnswer.
Pls, tell me, how to bind buttons and table data and popup window Save action.

javascript method:

```
function showPopupWindow() {
    document.getElementById('popupWindow').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
}
```

css-style:

```
#popupWindow {
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    background: url("../img/binding_dark.png");
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #000;
    opacity: 0.9;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remember there is no magic to make the server aware of *anything* you could have done in javascript client side.

The only way you can send data from client to server (except using Ajax calls) is to send *what is contained is a single form*. How the hell could the server guess what are the other values since the form contains only *one* field and there is no reference to the question in URL ?

As you opened the popup with javascript, you should use javascript to modify the DOM of the `div id="popupWindow"`. You can :

- either add a hidden field in the form for the `questionId` and use a custom update query to modify only the appropriate attributes (more exactly : add the field in the jsp and modify the value in the DOM via javascript)
- or add the `questionId` in the action URL and use it server side as a `@PathVariable` to automatically retrieve the selected question

I know there is a good deal of work remaining, but this is enough to understand why it doesn not work and how to change your application to make it work.

Comment: man, I thought it would be bad practice to use 2 ways you said. As you can see, I forget to remove setAtributes function from button onclick event. I send question.id to script variable questionId, and then get it thorught the hiddent input-element. But as I said, I thougth it would be wrong. But anyway, thanks for your patience, attention and reply. Really thx!